# Can I call multivariate functions with function sqlCol using metaprogramming in DolphinDB?

Tags: sql, metaprogramming, dynamic-sql, dolphindb

The following code queries in-memory table t while keeping 2 decimal places for column “price”:

```
t = table(`GME`AMC`KOSS as symbol, 32.512 13.26 64 as price);
sql(select=sqlCol(round(price,2)), from=t).eval();
```

I get an error message saying

```
Cannot recognize the token price
```

What is the correct way to call function `round` with `sqlCol`?

Answer (score 0):

Partial application can be used in DolphinDB by fixing one argument of function `round`. In this way, only one argument is passed:

```
t = table(`GME`AMC`KOSS as symbol, 32.512 13.26 64 as price);
sql(select=sqlCol("price", round{,2}), from=t).eval();
```

The result would be:

```
price
32.51
13.26
64
```